# Keyboard shortcut to list methods or properties

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to list properties or methods of an object being operated. I don't want to put `.` dot after deleting a wrong selection. That is, I don't want to press dot, select method/property, then remove the being selected including the dot, and put the dot again to see them etc.
When I put dot, assume dropdown choosing menu doesn't appear, is there a shortcut to show the dropdown selection menu?

Comment: can you be more specific? I quite didn't understand what you want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default keyboard shortcut for *CompleteWord* is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>, which will list all words available for completion in the current context.

(All of the default keyboard shortcuts for Visual Studio are [available here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019))